# How to send proper HTTP request and handle the response?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I have written a function to send a POST request:

```
pub async fn make_login_request(
    client: &Client,
    host: &String,
    credentials: &HashMap<String, String>,
) -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    client
        .post(
            &(String::from("https://")
                + &String::from(host)
                + &String::from("/[URL]")),
        )
        .json(&credentials)
        .header(
            CONTENT_TYPE,
            "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        )
        .send()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Now I have to validate the response. If the connection is lost, I need to break and exit the program. If it's another error code like 401, I need to exit as well, otherwise show success when 200.

How can I handle all these scenarios when I call `make_login_request`? If I call it like

```
make_login_request(&client, &host, &credentials)
```

how can I throw error with details in case of any error or return/print success?

Comment: [`Response::error_for_status`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.error_for_status) should do the trick. If not, please extend your ***question in your post*** why this doesn't fit your needings.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!